# *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 51 beyond bounds [0 .. 50] error when I use UIsearchbar and UItableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

```
 -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
 {
if (searchText.length == 0)
    isActive = NO;
else
    isActive = YES;

NSMutableArray *tmpSearched = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *tmpSearchedNumber = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSUInteger count1=0;
//NSUInteger count2=0;

for(count1=0;count1<[tableStationData count] || [tableData count];count1++)
{
    NSRange range = [[tableStationData objectAtIndex:count1] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange range1= [[tableData objectAtIndex:count1]rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if(range.location !=NSNotFound || range1.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [tmpSearchedNumber addObject:[tableStationData objectAtIndex:count1]];
        [tmpSearched addObject:[tableData objectAtIndex:count1]];
    }
}
```

where tableData Array size is : 2530
and same array size tableStationData. when i search on UISearchbar that coding gives error.

Comment: your for loop say either take tableStationData count or tableData count. and in the loop you are taking ranges for both. this is bit tricky. does tableData and  tableStationData contains same number of elements in it? if not then it is the issue you can't get ranges like this you should add some condition inside the loop. if my guess is right let me know i'll send code for it

Comment: yes both array have same element and when i search in uisearchbar than it's give error. @CharanGiri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this

```
for(count1=0;count1<[tableStationData count] || [tableData count];count1++)
```

for this

```
for(count1=0;count1<[tableStationData count] && count1<[tableData count];count1++)
```

EDIT: corrected the last line with *rmaddy*'s ovservation.

The way you're using the loop condition will always be true if `tableData` has at least 1 element, and the loop will never exit.

Comment: The condition is wrong. It should be `count1<[tableStationData count] && count1<[tableData count]`. Use `&&`, not `,`.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, I overlooked this (I'm used to the allowed usage of commas in the other two parts of the `for(;;)` statement

Comment: Those aren't commas, they are semicolons.

Comment: @rmaddy I was referring to the allowed usage of commas like this: `for (i=0,j=0; condition; i++,j++);`

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
for(count1=0;count1<[tableStationData count] || [tableData count];count1++)
```

This part:

```
 || [tableData count]
```

will always be true if there is at least one element in your tableData array, so it will exceed your maximum from tableStationData

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in for loop. Suppose tableStationData has 15 elements, tableData has 10 elements. The loop is running up to count1 is 9, when count1 is 10 , loop is running but inside loop, [tableStationData objectAtIndex:count1] works fine and [tableData objectAtIndex:count1] does not work, tableData has only 10 elements and it doesn't have 11th element. So we gets error in this case like `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]:`.

```
for(count1=0;count1<[tableStationData count] || [tableData count];count1++)
{
    NSRange range = [[tableStationData objectAtIndex:count1] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange range1= [[tableData objectAtIndex:count1]rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}
```

Comment: You are reading the code incorrectly. Look closely at the condition in the `for` loop. The problem is that the 2nd half of the condition (after the `||`) doesn't make use of the `count1` variable. And the `||` should be `&&` to ensure the loop stops based on whichever array is shorter.

Comment: In your case, that is right. I am explaining the different way. If he use for loop same like that, i am telling about inside loop. He should get errors. I am explaining to him where he will get errors. So indirectly, i am telling to him that check the for loop.